# Retrieving YouTube subscriber thumbnails over https

Tags: html, ajax, youtube-api

Is it possible to show the thumbnails for an embedded YouTube playlist that is subscribing to a feed over https instead of http?

I'm working on an area of a site that is https and retrieving these thumbnails over http is causing a security warning pop-up, which I am trying to get rid of.

The thumbnails are being requested as part of the YouTube API so unable to directly request them over https:

```
// loop through JSON and assign values to My obj
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

            TheVideo.My[i] = {};
            ja = jsonArticles[0][i];

            TheVideo.My[i].img = ja.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;

        }
```

What i'm directly looking for is to call the thumbnail from https instead of http when .url is called in the last line above.

EDIT:

I've found a work around to the problem, but I've edited my original post to clarify a bit what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit of an add-on but it does the job. I appended a replace method to request it from https instead of http:

```
// loop through JSON and assign values to My obj
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {

            TheVideo.My[i] = {};
            ja = jsonArticles[0][i];

            TheVideo.My[i].img = ja.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url.replace('http://','https://');

        }
```

Nice to know that this is possible in these situations.

Hope that this can potentially answer questions for someone else.